# Что происходит с моим JDK

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, awk, jdk11

Помогите разобраться!

```
oem@oem-GL72-6QD:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME

/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle

oem@oem-GL72-6QD:~$ update-java-alternatives -l

awk: cannot open /usr/lib/jvm/*.jinfo (No such file or directory)

jdk1.8.0_321                              /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_321


/etc/environment


PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_321"
J2SDKDIR="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_321/bin"
J2REDIR="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_321/jre"
DERBY_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_321/db"
                                         

oem@oem-GL72-6QD:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java

There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_321            1         auto mode

  1            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_321            1         manual mode

  2            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_321/bin/java   1         manual mode
```

Копчиком чую где то прописана 17я jdk ) куда смотреть?

Comment: в ~/.profile и в ~/.bashrc смотрели?

Comment: перелогиниться (или хотя бы профиль сорснуть) после `update-alternatives` не зыбыл?

Comment: Спасибо за внимание. Я еще только осваиваю линукс. В процессе гуглежа заглядывал в .bashrc, что смотреть там особо не знаю, но ничего про export $HOME_JAVA не увидел. В профайле тоже. Также слабо представляю что значит профиль сорснуть, но перегружался многократно и молитвы читал.

Comment: два дня уже развлекаюсь

Comment: Спасибо Andrew Bystrov. Ваш коммент указал куда рыть.

Answer (score 0):

Дело оказалось в файле etc/profile - добавил эти строчки и все стало ок.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

Comment: Лучше перенесите это строчки в ~/.profile и  ~/.bashrc  (это конкретно ваши настройки, а изменения в `/etc/profile`  повлияют на всех пользователей в системе (даже тех, кого казалось бы нв вашем компе и нет (см. cat /etc/passwd)))

Comment: Спасибо avp, так и сделаю

Comment: отдельное спасибо за наводку на etc/passwd